# If $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, then there is a measurable $f$ with $X=f(Y)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be real-valued random variables on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$. The statement in the title can be proved by a monotone class argument: Let $$\mathcal H:=\left\{f(Y)\mid f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\text{ is Borel measurable and bounded}\right\}\;.$$ It's easy to see that

1. $A\in\sigma(Y)\Rightarrow 1_A\in\mathcal H$
2. $F,G\in\mathcal H$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha F+G\in\mathcal H$

However, I've got problems to understand why

3. $F:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is bounded and $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal H$ with $F_n\ge 0$ and $F_n\uparrow F$ $\Rightarrow$ $F\in\mathcal H$

By definition, there are Borel measurable and bounded $f_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $F_n=f_n(Y)$. I've found a proof (see [Corollary A.10](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/552/bbm%253A978-88-470-1781-8%252F1.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fbook%2Fbbm%3A978-88-470-1781-8%2F1&token2=exp=1474226172~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F552%2Fbbm%25253A978-88-470-1781-8%25252F1.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fbook%252Fbbm%253A978-88-470-1781-8%252F1*~hmac=1e9583f639b8efdc190964cdd10eec541a1375c765e0669f48811600fd93eeeb)) where they define $$f:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n$$ and claim that $f(Y)\in\mathcal H$. Clearly, $f$ is Borel measurable, but I don't think that we can assume that $f$ is bounded. That would be true, if $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ would be **uniformly** bounded, but we don't know that. So, what am I missing?

Comment: One assumes that $F$ is bounded hence indeed one can choose $(f_n)$ such that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @did Maybe it's sufficient to define $f$ to be $\sup_{n}f_n$ on $Y(\Omega)$ and to be $0$ on $\mathbb R\setminus Y(\Omega)$?

Comment: You are right that $f$ need not be bounded, unless $Y$ is surjective. To fix this, notice that by hypothesis, $0\le F(\omega)\le M$, $\forall \omega\in\Omega$, for some constant $M$. Replace $f$ by $\min(f,M)$.